# How to solve AHCI and Sata interface

Tags: ssd, ahci

[image: Magician screenshot]

I have an Samsung 850 Evo 256 Gb as you can see the Samsung magician tells me that I don't have AHCI mode although I set the Windows registry for that mode by creating Msahci sub-key and modifying it's volume to 0.

Another problem is it tells that it's unable to detect SATA interface.

Is there any sort of tweak that I should do on boot menu?

My motherboard is a Gigabyte P41T-D3P and I'm using SATA II interface for the SSD.

Comment: It doesnt matter, "I'm using SATA II" so you wont see full performance anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what SATA mode it is running in in your BIOS. Instructions for your model are [here](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-p41t-d3p_v1.3_e.pdf)

[image]

> **On-Chip SATA Mode**
>
> Configures the integrated SATA controller.
>
> Disabled - Disables the integrated SATA controller.
>
> Auto - Lets the BIOS set SATA devices to Combined or Enhanced mode.
>
> If your onboard SATA controller is automatically configured to Combined mode,
> you can manually re-configure it to Enhanced mode as needed. (Default)
>
> Combined - Sets all SATA devices to operate in PATA mode. Combined allows a
> maximum of 4 ATA devices to be used simultaneously: two PATA devices
> plus two SATA devices.
> Enhanced - Sets all SATA devices to operate in SATA mode.
>
> Non-Combined - Sets all SATA devices to operate in PATA mode and disables the integrated IDE controller

For best results your On-Chip SATA mode should be in `Enhanced`, to allow the drives to work in AHCI. ***NOTE*** - This can stop Windows booting properly if the AHCI driver is not available to it upon first boot, and you may have to swap back to the setting you were on before. It sounds like you already did the required steps to allow this, but in case, you can find them [here](http://blog.jahnstek.com/2011/04/switch-from-ata-to-ahci-in-windows-7.html)

> - Start "regedit.exe"
> - Browse to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\msahci\
> - Change the DWord value named "Start" from "3" (ATA) to "0" (AHCI)
> - Shutdown the computer
> - Power the computer back on, making sure to enter the BIOS and change the SATA Operation to AHCI
> - Save the change